# Add a logo to Substrate Native Token

Tags: substrate-node-template, token, moonbeam

I want to add a logo to my native token on Substrate. I've seen it's implemented for multiple Substrate-based chains, but I couldn't find their implementation logics. Like [here](https://github.com/PureStake/moonbeam/tree/master/media) are the logos for Moonbeam native tokens, GLMR & MOVR, but I don't see where they are using these media files.

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Substrate doesn't provide this feature natively.

I believe they just put these in their repository for third-party usage.

Comment: I think we could set the logo in a Token's metadata for other chains, but there's no metadata file for the substrate native token. Any idea how can we set that?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a PR to Polkadot-JS apps to be able to set your custom logo among other things.
Here's an example : https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/pull/6890

Comment: would it be visible in metamask too?